# What genre is the song “Other Friends” from Steven Universe?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I really like this music, and I want to hear more.  What genre would this be considered?

**Link:** [“Other Friends” from the *Steven Universe* movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v_KfioWSf4)

Comment: @PiedPiper fixed

Answer (score 3):

This is based on an old American jazz- and ragtime-influenced pop music style from the 1930s and 40s called "[Tin Pan Alley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNliJQ5MHYk)" (after the [location where the songwriters would work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_Pan_Alley)).  The clues are the jazzy rhythm of the lyrics, the Dixieland instrumentation, and the peppy 4/4 beat.

Examples:

- [Happy Days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqsT4xnKZPg)
- [Puttin' on the Ritz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAZhHXsknd8)

However the *Steven Universe* song is a modern take on the music, similar to late revivals of the sound such as the hit synth pop remake of ["Ritz"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OA358YVquP8), or Madonna's "[Now I'm following you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz10YVp-1Ng)".

It might even be considered an [electroswing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_swing) number, like the music of [Caravan Palace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBGSJ3sbivI) or "[Lucas with the Lid Off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fRcFSbAcmE)" --electroswing is a modernized version of big-band swing, generally including samples of original vintage songs, but with modern beats and production.